# Elasticsearch _reindex fails

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

I am working on AWS Elasticsearch. It doesn't allow open/close index, so setting change can not be applied on the index.

In order to change the setting of a index, I have to create a new index with new setting and then move the data from the old index into new one.

So first I created a new index with

```
PUT new_index
{
  "settings": {
    "max_result_window":3000000,
    "analysis": {
      "filter": {
        "german_stop": {
          "type":       "stop",
          "stopwords":  "_german_"
        },
        "german_keywords": {
          "type":       "keyword_marker",
          "keywords":   ["whatever"]
        },
        "german_stemmer": {
          "type":       "stemmer",
          "language":   "light_german"
        }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "my_german_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer":  "standard",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "german_stop",
            "german_keywords",
            "german_normalization",
            "german_stemmer"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

it succeeded. Then I try to move data from old index into new one with query:

```
POST _reindex
{
  "source": {
    "index": "old_index" 
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "new_index"
  }
}
```

It failed with

```
Request failed to get to the server (status code: 504)
```

I checked the indices with _cat api, it gives

```
health status index          uuid                   pri rep docs.count docs.deleted store.size pri.store.size
yellow open   old_index      AGj8WN_RRvOwrajKhDrbPw   5   1    2256482       767034      7.8gb          7.8gb
yellow open   new_index      WnGZ3GsUSR-WLKggp7Brjg   5   1      52000            0    110.2mb        110.2mb
```

Seemingly some data are loaded into there, just wondering why the _reindex doesn't work.

Comment: Can you check ES logs ? Status code 504 means that you dint get timely response. May be because the reindexing was still going on. Are you having any proxy server in mid ?

Comment: @krrish the reindexing is still running in the background and completed afterwards successfully

Comment: That means there is nothing wrong with your ES.

Comment: If you are using AWS Elasticsearch, this is probably happening because the request timed out. As you know, reindexing can take a long time depending on the size of the target index. The default timeout in AWS ES at the time of my writing this comment is 30 seconds, however, it can be changed.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the status of reindex with api:

```
GET _tasks?detailed=true&actions=*reindex
```

There is a "status" object in response which has field "total":

total is the total number of operations that the reindex expects to perform. You can estimate the progress by adding the updated, created, and deleted fields. The request will finish when their sum is equal to the total field.

Link to ES Documentation: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html